# python use __getitem__ for a method

Tags: python

is it possible to use **getitem** inside a method, ie

```
Class MyClass:
    @property
    def function(self):
        def __getitem__():
            ...
```

So I can do

```
A = MyClass()
A.function[5]
A.function[-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is a first-class object in python, so the idea should work (the syntax is off), though I'd suggest making `function` its own class with properties in it, and then utilizing it in MyClass, unless you have a very good data-hiding reason to not do so...

I'd like to point out that I'm assuming you want to have `function` return a subscriptable thing, not have a subscriptable list of functions. That's a different implementation (also can be done, though.)

For example, a subscriptable thing (you could have made just a `list`, too):

```
# python

> class FooFunc(list):
>   pass
> class Foo:
>   foofunc = FooFunc()
> f = Foo()
> f.foofunc.append("bar")
> f.foofunc[0]
'bar'
```

Comment: @ned: i meant that the concept is fine, and neglected to say that the syntax was off. updated and with example.

Comment: But in this case, the function itself doesn't contain the __getitem__ call. Here foofunc is a reference to a subclass of list.

Comment: @mcjeff: i think that's what he was looking for. and it does have a \__getitem__ call -- within the list superclass... it's a little confusing if he wants a subscriptable list of functions or a property that is subscriptable...

Comment: Yeah, the net syntax is the same, so that's probably fine. It's not a __getitem__ within a method, but eh, whatever. ;-)

Comment: it took a me a while to understand this answer. You have to define `__getitem__` in `class FooFunc`

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that will not work. Consider the underlying descriptor logic being called when you access an attribute that has been decorated as a @property.  The get method needs to return a value that will be used as the computed property `function`. In this case, function doesn't return anything (implicit None value for the property). Your subscripting will then attempt to index `None` and boom.

You could return an object from `function` that supported the `__getitem__` dunder method, though. That would syntactically "work" the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you try your code (after fixing the C in Class), you'll see it produces an error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable".

I think your best bet is to create a class with a `__getitem__`, and set `function` to an instance of that class.  Is there a reason it needs to be so complicated?